# How to use size in pixel and not relative to data dispersion in geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want those two graphics to be different by having the red dot proportional to the data (means the second must me 1000x times larger):

#### Graphic 1

```
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

point <- st_point(x = c(-80, 35))
dot <- st_sfc(point, crs = 4236)

(
  ggplot()
  +  geom_sf(data = nc)
  +  geom_sf(data = dot, aes(size = 5))
  + theme_minimal()
)
```

[image]

#### Graphic 2

```
(
  ggplot()
  +  geom_sf(data = nc)
  +  geom_sf(data = dot, aes(size = 5000))
  + theme_minimal()
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a size scale to tell ggplot how you want the numbers interpreted:

```r
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

point <- st_point(x = c(-80, 35))
dot <- st_sfc(point, crs = 4236)

(
  ggplot()
  +  geom_sf(data = nc)
  +  geom_sf(data = dot, aes(size = 5), color = 'red')
  + theme_minimal()
  + scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 10), limits = c(1, 10000))
)
```

[image]

Just ensure you use the same scale with other instances:

```r
(
  ggplot()
  +  geom_sf(data = nc)
  +  geom_sf(data = dot, aes(size = 5000), color = 'red')
  + theme_minimal()
  + scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 10), limits = c(1, 10000))
)
```

[image]

Comment: I had found the `range` parameter of scale_size_continuous but had not used the `limits` one that does the trick

Comment: @pietrodito you might want to check out `scale_size_area`, which gives a more faithful representation of point size in relation to the underlying numbers (it maps data to the area of the point rather than its radius)

Comment: This is exactly what I need